# SpringBoot @Transactional don't flush the session after an exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to save the entity. So I do save (entity) and when an exception occurs, I try to save (entity) after delete ().

However, because the `don't flush the session after an exception` statement was displayed and the query for exception was not executed, the propagation was set as shown below.

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional(TxType.SUPPORTS)
    public String saveIfPossibleElseDeleteAndSave(final String name){

        final User user = User.builder()
                .age(0)
                .name(name)
                .gender(User.Gender.MAN)
                .build();

        try{
            userRepository.save(user);
            return "SAVE";
        } catch(RuntimeException e){
            userRepository.deleteOneLimit1();
            userRepository.save(user);
            return "DELETE AND SAVE";
        }
    }
}
```

The above is done. The question is, is there anything that would be a problem when the method is executed many times a second?

In addition, is there any other way than the above code?

#### edit

If save () is executed and an error occurs, the syntax is printed. 
`java.sql.SQLException: The table 'users' is full`

The user table is a memory table, so if it is full, delete it and save it again.

Comment: Will it not be easy to check , delete if exists and save ? What exception is thrown on save ?

Comment: As a side note, if you *must* use exceptions to drive the logic of your application, you should catch more specific exceptions than `RuntimeException`. A `NullPointerException` is a `RuntimeException` as well. Are you sure you want to allow the execution to continue after an NPE, when something is evidently wrong with the state of your program?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `rollbackFor` field in order to define how you should act if a subclass or subclasses of `Throwable` will be thrown when a transaction will be rolling back on `RuntimeException` so define it by following way:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
```

Comment: Any `RuntimeException` or `Error` during the `txn` will mark that txn for rollback implicitly. Marking rollbackFor Throwable is a bad idea